# how to find an exact match with findstr

Tags: batch, java

The output of the command:

```
java -version
```

is:

```
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)
```

I want to limit this output to match version 1.8.0_341 So I do the following:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr "1.8.0_341"') do (echo %%i)
IF %%i == "1.8.0_341" (call :JavaFound) else (call :NoJava)
:JavaFound
echo OK
:NoJava
echo Fail
```

But the output is:

```
"1.8.0_341"
Runtime
fail
```

another way:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (@echo %%~g)
IF %%~g == "1.8.0_341" (call :JavaFound) else (call :NoJava)
:JavaFound
echo OK
:NoJava
echo Fail
```

out

```
1.8.0_341
Fail
OK
Fail
```

But I would prefer the output to be::

```
"1.8.0"
ok
```

I would prefer the output to be "1.8.0" instead "1.8.0_341" (cmd), because 341 is update version of 8. The idea is that it detects any version of java that starts with 1.8.0 (real version on windows: 8.0. Full version example: 8.0.3410.10) it can be 341 or higher or lower

What's wrong with my batch script?

PD: I guess the error is in [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html). I have tried several combinations of parameters of [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and none have worked for me. Maybe it only looks for the result in the first line

thanks

**Update [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688919/8747573) (Very long and complicated, but if someone has a simpler idea I appreciate it):**

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem We use the value the JAVACMD environment variable, if defined
rem and then try JAVA_HOME
set "_JAVACMD=%JAVACMD%"
if "%_JAVACMD"=="" (
  if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
  )
)
if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=java

rem Parses x out of 1.x; for example 8 out of java version 1.8.0_xx
rem Otherwise, parses the major version; 9 out of java version 9-ea
set JAVA_VERSION=0
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%_JAVACMD% -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
  set JAVA_VERSION=%%g
)
set JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:"=%
for /f "delims=.-_ tokens=1-2" %%v in ("%JAVA_VERSION%") do (
  if /I "%%v" EQU "1" (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%w
  ) else (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%v
  )
)

@echo %JAVA_VERSION%

IF %JAVA_VERSION% == 8 (goto :Java8Found) else (goto :NoJava)
:Java8Found
echo Java 8 Found
goto :eof
:NoJava
echo Fail
goto :eof

endlocal
```

out

```
8
Java 8 Found
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your testing as the 3rd match is `"1.8.0_341"` not `"1.8.0"`

Comment: @DavidPostill I would prefer the output to be "1.8.0" instead "1.8.0_341" (cmd), because 341 is update version of 8. The idea is that it detects any version of java that starts with 1.8.0 (real version on windows: 8.0. Full version example: 8.0.3410.10) it can be 341 or higher or lower

Comment: `findstr` is totally correct and has nothing to do with your problem. The problem with your own scripts is you try to access a `for` variable (`%%i` or `%%g`) AFTER the `for` ends, which doesn't work. You need to, as the 'workaround' does, use the `for` variable IN the body of the `for` to `set` a normal variable like `JAVA_VERSION` and subsequently you can use the normal variable. OTOH neither you nor the workaround needs the `2^>^&1` because `java -version` doesn't use stderr.

Answer (score 0):

> 3rd edit

```bath
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (ProgramFiles,ProgramFiles(x86^),ProgramW6432,nul);= do if defined %%~i (for /f delims^= %%z in (
'cmd.exe /v /q /c "2>nul where /r "!%%~i!\java" java.exe" ^| find /v /i "\jdk" ^| findstr /iel bin\java.exe
        ')do if "%%~nxz" == "java.exe" set "_javacmd=%%~z" && goto=%:^))else goto :nojava
%:^)
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^_^" %%g in =;('"!_javacmd!" -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "_java=%%~g" && (
     for /f tokens^=2delims^=. %%i in ('cmd.exe /v /c "call echo\!_java:_%_java:*_=%=!"
        ')do set "_java_version=%%~i" )

call set "_java-ver=!_java:_%_java:*_=%=!"
if !_java_version! equ 8 =;(goto :java8found );= else goto :nojava

:java8found
echo\"%_java-ver%" & echo\ok & endlocal & goto :eof

:nojava
echo\fail & endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

> 2nd edit

- More simple will be:

```bath
@echo off 
   
java -version 2>&1 | findstr /c:"1.8.0_341" >nul && (
    goto :JavaFound) || Goto :NoJava
   
:JavaFound
echo\ I'm here JavaFound zOk! & goto :eof
   
:NoJava
echo\ I'm here NoJava fail!
```

---

> 1st edit:

- The `Findstr` command tends to treat everything like regex, when
  passing the
  `/L` or `/c:` flag, this treatment will be given as strings literally.
- Use `Findstr /L "Literal String"` or `Findstr /c:"String Literal"`

```bath
 @echo off 
   
set "_str_out="
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^"_ %%i in (
   'java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /c:"1.8.0" ^|find /v ")" 
   ')do set "_str_out=%%~i"

if defined  _str_out (echo\"%_str_out%" & echo\ok)else echo\fail
```

---

In your `For` loop, you can change using multiple delimiters, in this case the double quotes and underscore: `delims^=^"_`

By using your `Findstr` to get the string you want and with a `Find /v ^)` to inhibit additional irrelevant lines in the loop, you get the strings and only it in the loop output

Comment: I see a couple of things to fix in your new script. 1. If java is not installed there is no output (:NoJava doesn't work). 2. There are no significant differences in the output of your command java -version 2>&1 | findstr /c:"1.8.0" with the output of my script